# Python Django - print within a loop, inside view function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find a way to print within a loop, inside a view function.

I want to do something like this:

```
def some_page(request):
    for i in range(1, 5):
        print("<span>current index: %s</span>") % (i)
```

But I need to use HttpResponse, (or render, but from what I learned until now, HttpResponse is for small things, like this)

so I need to do

```
return HttpResponse("<span>current...")
```

Which will not works - because `return` will end the function.

So how can i do function that will prints within loop ? (like the example above)

*With Python, not in the template (not Jinja)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a template?.. What have you tried?

Comment: You want to print to your console?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how django works, printing strings only outputs them to the console the server is running on, to render a page the view has to return a HttpResponse (alternatively using the render-shortcut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def some_page(request):
    s = ""
    for i in range(1, 5):
        s = s + "<span>current index: %s</span>" % i
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. Do this in a template, that's what they're for.

Comment: I agree, but I think he is just getting started.  I took it more as a python than a django question @DanielRoseman